# JsValue returned by executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue in a browser has a null jsContext if the browser is opened by another browser using window.open

Tags: jxbrowser

By debugging on it, i found that it could be related to thread issues. When a new browser is about to open, a OnAddNewContentsMessage and a OnDidCreateScriptContextMessage are initiated simultaneously on different thread. If i let OnAddNewContentsMessage thread resume first which would later create a new browser, OnDidCreateScriptContextMessage would work properly being caught by the new browser and create a jsContext, but if i let OnDidCreateScriptContextMessage thread resume first, it won't be caught by browser and no jsContext would be created. Running in non-debug mode works just like the latter. Having a null jsContext would make most of the operations on the JsValue throw a NullPointerException.

This problem only occurs in browsers  opened by another browser using window.open(url). It works fine if i refresh the browser or visit the url directly(typing or paste url into address bar).

================updated============
It also works fine if the new browser is opened by a href link. In this scenario, OnAddNewContentsMessage and OnDidCreateScriptContextMessage is initiated sequentially

Comment: i m using 6.x by the way

Comment: An updated EAP build with the fix is available for download: [https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.21-b6-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.21-b6-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip)

This fix will be included in the next official JxBrowser release.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in JxBrowser that will be resolved in one of the future versions. Unfortunately, there is no workaround for the current version.

UDP: The issue is fixed in JxBrowser 6.21.